# Error al intentar hacer ejecutable un sistema en java?

Tags: java

Hola pues quiero hacer ejecutable un sistema en **netbeans** pero al momento de intentar hacer el **jar** me arroja los siguientes mensajes de error:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 
1.7
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning
```

he hecho el mismo proceso pero con programas pequeños y si funciona pero con el sistema que tengo no funciona alguien sabría como arreglar el error?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez estas en Java 8/9 pero el compilador intenta generar todo para Java 7??, Comprueba mirando: miProyecto>Properties>Source/Binary Format ... (categoria Sources) y que la opción seleccionada sea la JDK que tengas instalada y no la JDK 1.7

Comment: Gracias por contestar pero ya hice lo que me dijiste y no funciono pero seguiré buscando haber si lo puedo arreglar :D.